# How to discover a new line using a for loop?

Tags: bash, shell, string

In various places around the web I've found:

```
\015 
\012
\x0a - hex
\n
\r
```

all as synonyms for various newlines / carriage returns...

But in this small script I cannot recognise when I come across a newline - can someone tell me what I should be checking for in the if line ?

```
#!/bin/bash

test="this is a
test"

for a in "$test"; do

        if [[ "$a" == '\012' ]] ; then
                echo "FOUND NEWLINE"
        fi

echo "$a"

done
```

Comment: I have a dumb question. Why do you need to do this? If you read input line by line `cat | while read line; do ...; done`, you know there was a carriage return for each iteration. If your input can be files with `\r` without `\n`, just transform the file `tr '\r' '\n'` while processing the input. If you just need to know if there are multiple lines: `wc -l`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Please don't edit your question this way, as it makes the existing answers meaningless. Since you've found a way to solve your problem, you may post it as an alternate answer.

Comment: @nicerobot if there is no newline at all, then `wc -l` will return 0; you should add that as an answer

Comment: @lolfrog the solution should not be in the question, you should mark the answer which has the solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you directly use strings under a `for` loop, it will work per-word (here on *one* word: the whole content of `$test` since it's quoted), not per-character. You need to use a `while` loop with `read` in order to parse letter-by-letter, or to introduce a numerical parameter that would iterate over the string.

In addition, when using `read`, you need to make sure that newlines and whitespaces aren't interpreted as delimiters and to force `read` to read one char at a time.

Here's a working version:

```
#!/bin/bash

test="this is a
test"

printf %s "$test" | while IFS= read -r -N 1 a; do

        if [[ "$a" == $'\n' ]] ; then
                echo "FOUND NEWLINE"
        fi

printf %s "$a"

done
```

You could replace `$'\n'` with `$'\012'` or `$'\x0a'`, since they all represent the same newline code. But it is not the same as `\015` or `\r` - this stands for *carriage return* (return to the beginning of line). On Linux systems, newlines are represented using `\n`, but on Windows for example, they are represented by a sequence of `\r\n` instead. That is why if you had a text file from Windows, you could detect newlines also by searching for `\r`.

Comment: In short, it is turning the quoted escape sequence like `\n` into its byte representation, so that you don't need to place ugly-looking, quoted line breaks in your test statement.

Answer (score 4):

You can check for newlines in a variable very easily in bash with:

```
[[ $var = *$'\n'* ]]
```

I find it more convenient to use:

```
declare -r EOL=$'\n' TAB=$'\t' # at top of script
..
if [[ $var = *$EOL* ]]; then # to test (no field-splitting in [[ )
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using `tr` and then `test`:

```
if [ -n "$(tr -cd '\n\r' < datafile)" ]; then
    echo "NEWLINE FOUND"
fi
```

The `tr -cd` removes everything except the newlines/carriage returns.  If there are newlines in the file, then there will be output from which the `-n` test will return true.

Comment: That won't work for files not containing `\r`s because command substitution removes the trailing newline characters (`"$(printf '\n\n\n\n\n')"` is the empty string).